# Whitney Embedding theorem for manifold with boundary in Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds(2nd Edition)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am reading through the new edition of Lee's book and I am stuck by the proof of Theorem 6.15. When passing to a non-compact manifold, the author begin by defining several sub-levelsets and claim that they're regular domains by 5.47. However, 5.47 only asserts the result for manifold without boundary, and the manifold in 6.15 could have non-empty boundary.

Is 5.47 true for manifold with boundary? The manifold without boundary case can be shown using the equivalence between embedded submanifolds and subsets satisfying the slice condition, such equivalence is only claimed (in the book) when the ambient manifold has no boundary (5.51)

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: 5.47 don't seem to be true for manifold with boundary...

Comment: This is a mistake.  Prop. 5.47 is definitely not true when $M$ is a manifold with boundary.  I'm thinking about the most efficient way to fix it, and eventually I'll post a correction.  Suggestions welcome.  (@Fang, sorry I haven't answered your email queries yet; been very busy.)

Comment: @JackLee Hey, has there been a fix? I can't find the relevant in the corrections page

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for the reminder -- I had completely forgotten about that. I've now posted a [correction](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).

Comment: @JackLee Thank you! And double thanks for the book, I can't take courses atm and wanted for a long time to learn about manifolds, and especially Whiteneys theorem. Can't wait to get to symplectic inequalities after finishing your book